# Adding a class instance variable and attr_reader to Ruby class at runtime?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-instance-variables

How do I add a class instance variable, the data for it and a attr_reader at runtime?

```
class Module
  def additional_data member, data
    self.class.send(:define_method, member)  {
      p "Added method #{member} to #{name}"
    }
  end
end
```

For example, given this class

```
class Test
  additional_data :status, 55
end
```

So that now I can call:

```
p Test.status # => prints 55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Object
  def self.additional_data(name, value)
    ivar_name = "@#{name}"

    instance_variable_set(ivar_name, value)

    self.class.send(:define_method, name) do
      instance_variable_get(ivar_name)
    end

    self.class.send(:define_method, "#{name}=") do |new_value|
      instance_variable_set(ivar_name, new_value)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  additional_data :bar, 'baz'
end

puts Foo.bar # => 'baz'
Foo.bar = 'quux'
puts Foo.bar # => 'quux'
```

It's pretty self-explanatory, but let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: instead of `self.class.send(:define_method, name) ...` why not just `self.class.define_method(name) ...`

Answer (score 4):

`Module#class_eval` is what you want:

```
def add_status(cls)
  cls.class_eval do
    attr_reader :status
  end
end

add_status(Test)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to be able to add the method status to any class, not just Test. I've updated the question with what I'm trying..

Comment: In Ruby everything is an object, if you can do `Test.class_eval ...` you can do `variable.class_eval ...` where `variable` is a class object. I've updated my answer with something that should better match what you want.

Comment: ...and obviously you can pass in the name of the attribute to the method if you want to.

Comment: Instead of `class_eval` you can also use `send`, which leads to the somewhat more concise: `cls.send(:attr_reader, :status)`